# Unhide desktop icons

Tags: macos, mac, desktop

I recently had tried to make some hidden desktop icons on my desktop following the instructions found [here](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/23/hide-all-desktop-icons-in-mac-os-x/). I am on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I ended up somehow making every file a hidden file. The files are all visible but are just transparent and I cannot open some of them.

How do I make all of these files become unhidden files so they are no longer transparent and I can access them better?

Comment: What exactly did you do to hide them?

Comment: I followed this tutorial. I am not sure what went wrong. http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/23/hide-all-desktop-icons-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Have you tried undoing what you did? If you ran that first command in the link, have you tried running `TRUE` instead of `FALSE` like in the link?

Comment: +1 to the above comment.

"defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true" will remediate your issue.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but for some reason all of the icons are still transparent and being shown as hidden files.

Comment: Can you posted a screenshot of what it looks like? Are the files that are showing up as transparent icons your actual files that were there before you ran the CreateDesktop defaults command?

Answer (score 1):

You might have accidentally show the hidden files in Finder. Try this command to hide all the hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool NO
```

To show it again, change the BOOL value from NO to YES:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES
```

Answer (score 0):

To unhide all icons on the desktop, simply open the terminal then run:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true
```

Then restart Finder with the following command (also in the terminal):

```
killall Finder
```

The reverse is true if you'd like to reverse this and hide icons on your desktop:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true
killall Finder
```

Here's [a video showing](https://youtu.be/1Bw8Wm8vz2I) the effect this will have.

Answer (score 0):

Download a program called [Clean Slate (free trial)](https://download.freedownloadmanager.org/Mac-OS/Clean-Slate/FREE-1.0.3.html). Once you download the free trial choose the option to remove desktop icons then uncheck the option, that's how I fixed the issue.